# Automatically run a php script

Tags: php, linux, cron

I am connecting to an eCommerce website's API, to get product reviews from them, what I want to do is to set the product ID which I want it's review using a loop iterator from 1 to 10, for example:

loop from i = 1 until 10
    product_id=i
    // here I want to tell my php script to resubmit itself with the new product_id

I found that cron would submit it to me, but then I won't be able to loop on the product_id, I will have to synchronize between the cron and the iterator in the php script which is not efficient solution at all. 
does anyone know how to help me

Comment: What specific problem are you having? Right now, it seems you want the PHP script written for you

Comment: Why can't you look over `product_id` inside your PHP script?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what *resubmitting the script* means, but cron should call the script with the loop.

Comment: of course I am now asking anyone to write my a script, u can look at baskax answer, he understood what I want correctly

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite your php script to use $argv 
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php

then you can pass it like

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..5}
do
   php script.php $i
done
```

save it as .sh file and add it to CRON

Comment: thanks bro, I believe that this is exactly what I wanted, but I don't actually understand how would corn excute it ?

Comment: well you have to save this .sh file in any location, make it executable with chmod +x then add an entry to your crontab where you specify how often your script will run. You should read about crontab and its syntax or use any crontab generator that suites your needs

Comment: mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm, thanks alot bro, I will try what you have suggested

Comment: you can use an iterator in your php script directly instead of using $argv[1] variable but you still need to use cron if you want to your script run automatically every X amount of time

Comment: I have saved what you have written in a file called collectRev.sh and wrote this line inside the cron file that I am excuting from cron 
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/sh -o result.txt /opt/lampp/htdocs/souq-api-php-master/collectRev.sh
but seems that nothing is working

Comment: is your collectRev.sh file executable? by the way what is sh -o option? Shouldn't you pipe your output with '>' operator?

Comment: yes it is executable , and I haven't tried piping in cron , i will search for it

Comment: I meant you should rather use
/usr/bin/sh /opt/lampp/..../collectRev.sh > result.txt
in crontab